# Both Firefox and Thunderbird have lost internet connection after upgrade to 22.04. Jellyfish has Wi-Fi connection

Tags: firefox, internet, 22.04

Upgraded from Unubtu 20.04 to 22.04.Firefox and Thunderbird now report No Internet connection. Wi-fi available as before.

Comment: please [edit] your question detailing the instructions you issued to achieve this upgrade...

Comment: Advised from "Software Updater" and clicked on update.
However other problems now come to the fore:
When now powered up asks for "Authentication" from a blank screen, when given screen stays blank.
However by using the advanced button states Linx 5.15.0.4 generic. Clicking on 5.15.0.4 reform jellyfish opens and Firefox and Thunderbird up and running. "Terminal" does not recognise password in trying to run "Sudo app update" as recommended and "software" still has no connection.